# $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, 2n \in A \Leftrightarrow 2n+1 \in A$ is a $\sigma -$algebra

Tags: measure-theory, functions

We have that $\Omega = \mathbb{Z}$.

i) Show that the class $\alpha$ of the subsets $A$ of $\Omega$ that verify :

$\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, 2n \in A \Leftrightarrow 2n+1 \in A$ is a $\sigma -$algebra.

ii)Show that the function $f: \Omega \rightarrow \Omega$ where $f(n)=n+2$ is measurable, is an injection and a surjection. Is $f^{-1}$ measurable?

For i:

$1) \ \mathbb{Z} \in \alpha $ because $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, \ 2n \in \mathbb{Z}\Leftrightarrow 2n+1 \in \mathbb{Z}$

$2) \ A \in \alpha \Rightarrow A^{c} \in \alpha $ because $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}\ ,\ \ 2n \in A^{c} \Rightarrow 2n+1 \in A^{c}$.

Otherwise, if $2n \in A^{c}$ and $2n+1 \in A \Rightarrow 2n \in A$ so $2n \in A \cap A^{c}$ (it's a contradiction)

If $2n+1 \in A^{c}$ and $2n \in A \Rightarrow 2n+1 \in A$ so $2n+1 \in A \cap A^{c}$ (it's a contradiction)

$3) \ A_{i} \in \alpha , i \in \mathbb{N} \Rightarrow \forall i \in \mathbb{N} \ \forall n \in \mathbb{N}, \ 2n \in A_{i} \Leftrightarrow 2n+1 \in A_{i}$.

$\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} A_{i} \in \alpha$ because $2n \in \bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} A_{i} \Rightarrow 2n \in A_{k} \Leftrightarrow 2n+1 \in A_{k} \Leftrightarrow 2n+1 \in \bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} A_{i}$

For ii:

I showed that $f$ is an increasing function so $f$ is a bijection.

$ \forall m \in \mathbb{Z} : f(m-2) = m \Rightarrow f$ is a surjection.

I don't know how to check if $f, f^{-1}$ is countable.

Comment: What is a countable function?

Comment: Ι meant measurable.$$f: \Omega \rightarrow \Omega $$ is measurable if, for every $a$, the set $\{x \in \Omega : f(x) > a\}$ is measurable.

Comment: No, $f: (X, \mathcal{A}_X) \to (Y,\mathcal{A}_Y)$ measurable means $f^{-1}[M]$ is in $\mathcal{A}_X$ when $M \in \mathcal{A}_Y$.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof that $\mathcal{A} = \{A \subseteq \Bbb Z: \forall n \in \Bbb Z: 2n \in A \iff (2n+1 \in A)\}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra is a bit confused.

If you play with finding sets in it, you'll soon find that it is actually the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the partition $A_n = \{2n, 2n+1\}$, $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ of $\mathbb{Z}$, and every set $A \in \mathcal{A}$ is of the form $S(B):=\bigcup_{n \in B} A_n$ for some $B \subseteq \Bbb Z$. E.g, check that the latter set obeys the defining property of $\mathcal{A}$ and it's clearly a $\sigma$-algebra ($S(B^\complement)=S(B)^\complement$ and $S(A \cap B)=S(A) \cap S(B)$ etc.) and $\mathcal{A}$ contains all $A_n$ etc.

Now $f^{-1}[A_n]=A_{n-1}$ which clearly shows $f$ is measurable, as its generating set has measurable pre-images. But the same also holds for $g:=f^{-1}: n \to n-2$, etc.